# REGEXP_MATCH in Data Studio

Tags: mysql, sql, looker-studio

I am currently using datastudio to transform my data into reporting and I had problems in creation because the data available is not very exploitable. I would like to clean them through the regexp functions but I can't find the right expression

Exemple :

```
      1- Apple
      2- Apples
      3 - Pre-apple
      4- Pré-apples
      5-Prèapple
```

I'm looking to transform to

```
      Apple
      Preapple
```

Can someone help me please? , thank you !

Comment: You can test your regex with some data at https://regex101.com/ . `[a-zA-Z]*(?<!-)[aA]pple$` should work. Or you can clean your data in multiple steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement with a couple of [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) functions does the trick:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field, ".*(Pr[eèé]-?apples?).*") THEN "Preapple"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Field, ".*(Apples?).*") THEN "Apple"
  ELSE "Other"
END
```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f20a6d84-004e-46d3-be37-f25f05dbd1a4) to demonstrate:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want everything after the first "- ".  For this use `instr()` and `substr()`:

```
select substr(col, instr(col, '- ') + 2)
```

Usually, in MySQL, the simplest solution is `substring_index()`.  But you might have multiple `'- '` and you only care about the first one.  If you don't, then:

```
select substring_index(col, '- ', 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I think that I did not express myself well, I modified the example so that you see more my need :)